# Somar variáveis com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte função em Javascript:

```
function soma(){

var pacote = document.getElementsByName('Pacote');
    for (var i = 0; i < pacote.length; i++){
        if ( pacote[i].checked ) {
            if(pacote[i].value == "Pacote i"){
                var ValorPacoteI = 1000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote ii") {
                var ValorPacoteII = 2000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote iii") {
                var ValorPacoteIII = 3000.00;
            }
        }
    }
var somar = ValorPacoteI + ValorPacoteII + ValorPacoteIII;
alert(somar.toFixed(2));
}
```

Estou precisando somar os valores dos pacotes, porém quando seleciono o primeiro e o segundo, aparece NuN, só marcando o terceiro que faz o cálculo.Como eu faria para que o usuário selecionar qualquer um dos pacotes o cálculo seja efetuado, sem ser obrigatório clicar em todos?

Comment: Podes mostrar o HTML que tens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa declarar as variáveis na sua função para ter acesso a msm dentro da função, logo que , declarando ela dentro do bloco IF, você só vai ter acesso nesse bloco de código, declarando ela no inicio da função soma(), temos acesso a msm por toda a função

```
function soma(){

var ValorPacoteI = 0;
var ValorPacote2 = 0;
var ValorPacote3 = 0;

var pacote = document.getElementsByName('Pacote');
    for (var i = 0; i < pacote.length; i++){
        if ( pacote[i].checked ) {
            if(pacote[i].value == "Pacote i"){
                ValorPacoteI = 1000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote ii") {
                ValorPacoteII = 2000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote iii") {
                ValorPacoteIII = 3000.00;
            }
        }
    }
var somar = ValorPacoteI + ValorPacoteII + ValorPacoteIII;
alert(somar.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: adicionar a explicação da mudança vai melhorar sua resposta

Comment: Perfeito Renan. Funcionou! Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Esqueci de explicar, desculpa @Sanção.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos , deu certo ? pode marcar a resposta como resolvido ? e por nada, qualquer coisa estou a disposição.

Comment: Deu sim Renan. Tentei marcar naquela hora, mas tive que esperar alguns minutos para fazer a marcação rs rs. Marquei como resolvido ;)

Comment: Há uma falha conceitural na sua resposta @RenanDegrandi. Relativa à declaração de variáveis em JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Vou copiar a resposta do Renan Degrandi apenas para corrigir uma falha de conceito sobre JavaScript.

Considere o código à seguir:

```
function soma(){

var pacote = document.getElementsByName('Pacote');
    for (var i = 0; i < pacote.length; i++){
        if ( pacote[i].checked ) {
            if(pacote[i].value == "Pacote i"){
                var ValorPacoteI = 1000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote ii") {
                var ValorPacoteII = 2000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote iii") {
                var ValorPacoteIII = 3000.00;
            }
        }
    }
var somar = ValorPacoteI + ValorPacoteII + ValorPacoteIII;
alert(somar.toFixed(2));
}
```

Embora o problema seja causado pela declaração das variáveis dentro do IF, o porque disso causar problema está errado.
Em JavaScript não existe escopo de bloco. Existem apenas escopo de função ou o escopo global.
Sendo assim, declarar a variável dentro do IF é o mesmo que:

```
function soma(){
//As declarações de variáveis são movidas para o topo do escopo, neste caso a função soma.
var ValorPacoteI;
var ValorPacote2;
var ValorPacote3;

var pacote = document.getElementsByName('Pacote');
    for (var i = 0; i < pacote.length; i++){
        if ( pacote[i].checked ) {
            if(pacote[i].value == "Pacote i"){
              // No entanto a atribuição permanece no mesmo lugar do código.
                ValorPacoteI = 1000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote ii") {
              // No entanto a atribuição permanece no mesmo lugar do código.
                ValorPacoteII = 2000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote iii") {
              // No entanto a atribuição permanece no mesmo lugar do código.
                ValorPacoteIII = 3000.00;
            }
        }
    }
/*Sendo assim, quando apenas um ou dois checkboxes estiverem marcados,
 o valor das variáveis referentes aos que não estiverem marcados serão sempre undefined.
Quando tentamos calcular qualquer número contra um valor undefined 
o resultado é um NaN(Not a Number). */
var somar = ValorPacoteI + ValorPacoteII + ValorPacoteIII;
alert(somar.toFixed(2));
}
```

Ao mover a declaração das variáveis para o topo da função, o que aconteceu na verdade foi que o valor inicial das variáveis foi mudado de undefined para 0(zero). O que possibilitou o cálculo.

```
function soma(){
   var ValorPacoteI = 0;
   var ValorPacote2 = 0;
   var ValorPacote3 = 0;
/*...*/
}
```

Este comportamento é chamado de "Declaration Hoisting", ou "Içamento da Declaração". Você pode saber mais sobre o assunto neste link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

E abaixo a forma de resolver o problema:
(Não é a forma que eu preferiria para resolver este problema. Porém é mais próxima do seu próprio código).

```
function soma(){
var somar = 0,
    pacote = document.getElementsByName('Pacote');
    for (var i = 0, len=pacote.length; i < len; i++){
        if ( pacote[i].checked ) {
            if(pacote[i].value == "Pacote i"){
                somar = somar + 1000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote ii") {
                somar = somar + 2000.00;
            }else if (pacote[i].value == "Pacote iii") {
                somar = somar + 3000.00;
            }
        }
    }
   alert(somar.toFixed(2));
}
```